# How to detect the navigation button press on on HTC desire?

Tags: android, navigation

I'm testing a program on an HTC desire phone. There's a special button on the right of the menu button. It's a circle. It's used to navigate. You can also press it.

I would like to detect when someone presses it over a row of my `ListView`.

I did try putting in a `convertView.setOnKeyListener((OnKeyListener)...`, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about the track-ball?

Comment: I must say that i am in a listview, located in the custom adapter that is managing the convertview from the getView function. From what I saw in other software, pressing the nav button should send me a click event but apparently it doesnt... :(

Comment: I did put a convertView.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)... that is working perfectly with the touch screen but not with the nav button pression... dont know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the good way is to listen to the OnClick event from the listview and not from the adapter... Because there is a difference...

See here : [android onClick event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751528/android-onclick-event-not-firing)